# Servlet works only for one jsp form

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I started experimenting a little bit with JSPs and Servlets.I have a project that lets you create an account and saves user data in Oracle db.I have created a form that allows the user to make a quick log-in,from the webapps header using email and password fields:

```
 <jsp:include page="/includes/header.jsp" />
 <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
 <link href="<c:url value='sources/css/logIn.css'/>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"   />

<form action="logIn" method="post">
       <table>
            <td>
                <div id="header_logo"> 
                      <a href="<c:url value='/welcome.jsp'/>"> 
                          <img src="<c:url value='/sources/images/logo.jpg'/>">
                      </a>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                Dont have an account?
            </td> 
            <td>
               <a href ="create_account.jsp"> JOIN! </a></td>
            <td class="header_label" align="left">
              <div id ="header_email">
                  email Address<br>
                 <input type="text" name="logEmailAddress" size="15" value="" class="header_input">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="header_label" align="left">
                <div id="header_password">
                     password<br>
                     <input type="password" name="logPassword" size="15" value="" class="header_input">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div id="header_submit">
                  <br><input id="sub" type="submit" value="Log In">
               </div>
             </td>
      </table>
   </form>
```

I use post method to call the LogInServlet which looks like this:

```
package appUsers;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import business.User;
import data.UserDB;


public class LogInServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
        String logEmailAddress = request.getParameter("logEmailAddress");
        String logPassword = request.getParameter("logPassword");
        String url = "";
        String message ="";
        boolean isLogged=false;


        //debug message
        System.out.println("user input is emailaddress: " + logEmailAddress + " and password: " + logPassword);

        if (logEmailAddress.length()==0 || logPassword.length()==0)
        {
            message = "Please provide your email address and password";
            url = "/welcome.jsp";
        }


        User user = UserDB.selectUser(logEmailAddress);

        if (user!=null)
        {
            isLogged = logPassword.equals(user.getPassword());
            System.out.println(isLogged);

            if(isLogged)
            {
                 message = "You have succesfully loged in";
                 url = "/welcome.jsp";  


            }
            else
            {
                message = "Invalid password";
                url = "/welcome.jsp";
            }
        }
        else
        {
           message = "No such account";
           url = "/welcome.jsp"; 
        }

         HttpSession session = request.getSession();
         session.setAttribute("user", user);
         session.setAttribute("isLogged", isLogged);
         request.setAttribute("message",message);

        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}

}
```

The function that selects the user from the db:

> > > > User user = UserDB.selectUser(logEmailAddress);

is implemented like this:

```
public static User selectUser(String emailAddress)
    {
    ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String query = "SELECT * FROM USERS " + "WHERE EmailAddress = ?";
    try
    {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, emailAddress);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        User user = null;

        if (rs.next())
        {
            user = new User();
            user.setFirstName(rs.getString("FirstName"));
            user.setLastName(rs.getString("LastName"));
            user.setEmailAddress(rs.getString("EmailAddress"));
            user.setUserName(rs.getString("UserName"));
            user.setPassword(rs.getString("Password"));
            user.setUserType(rs.getString("Type"));
        }

        return user;
    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }        
    finally
    {
        DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

All of the above work fine together, user is selected from DB and confirms users account when logging in from header fields.

Yesterday i tried to create a similar form which is displayed in the main view calling the same Servlet using post method:

```
<jsp:include page="/includes/header.jsp" />
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<link href="<c:url value='sources/css/logIn.css'/>" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"   />

    <div id="log">
        <h1>Log in to Triptip</h1>

            <form action="logIn" method="post">
                 <table>
                    <tr class="spaceBetweenRows">
                             <td class="user_label" align="left">
                                 email Address<br>
                             </td>
                             <td>
                               <input class="user_input" type="text" name="logEmailAddress" value=" ">
                             </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td class="user_label" align="left">
                                password<br>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                 <input class="user_input" type="password" name="logPassword" value="">
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td align="right">
                            <br>
                            <input id="sub" type="submit" value="Log In">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
               </table>
            </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Although i have confirmed that attributes Email and Password are being passed correctly to the Servlet the User user = UserDB.selectUser(logEmailAddress); returns null although the user exists!

Anybody have an idea of what might be going on? I tried implementing a new servlet but with the same outcome!Any help would be appreciated since i spent a lot of latenight hours trying to figure this thing out!

I'm using Windows 7 64, Netbeans, 7.4 Java 1.7.0-51, Tomcat 7 and Oracle 11.2XE

Comment: Did you delete the initial space in your new `logEmailAddress` field? I notice you are defaulting it to " ".

Comment: Now i just feel silly!!I could have spent another 5 hours trying to figure this thing out and still might not have seen this!Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you set a default value that includes a space -

```
<input class="user_input" type="text" name="logEmailAddress" value=" ">
```

Based on your comment, you didn't notice that and simply added more characters. You don't need a default value so it could be,

```
<input class="user_input" type="text" name="logEmailAddress" value="">
```

or just

```
<input class="user_input" type="text" name="logEmailAddress">
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have specified

```
<input class="user_input" type="text" name="logEmailAddress" value=" ">
```

so whenever you enter some value in the text-field like `abc` and when you do

```
String email = request.getParameter("logEmailAddress");
```

email shall give you `initialspace+abc`
so change

```
<input class="user_input" type="text" name="logEmailAddress" value=" ">
```

to

```
<input class="user_input" type="text" name="logEmailAddress" value="">
```